# C: Print only not common elements in 2 arrays

Tags: c, array-difference

I have some C code I want to modify really simple.

Let's say I have two arrays like this

```
   int v1[5] = {1, 3, 7, 13, 10};
   int v2[2] = {1, 10};
```

And I would like to print the not common elements (difference) like:

```
3, 7, 13
```

Here is my attempt which is not enough yet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int v1[5] = { 1, 3, 7, 13, 10 };
    int v2[2] = { 1, 10 };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(v1) / (sizeof * v1); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(v2) / (sizeof * v2); j++) {
            if (v1[i] != v2[j]) {
                printf("%d ", v1[i]);
                break;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The two arrays will be always really short (max 6 elements). Thery are not ordered and I should not modify them. The elements in each of them are unique, that is each number can only appear 1 time in each array. v2 will only contains a subset of element from v1.
What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: As a beginning, what for `break` statement in if(){}else{} statement? You execute it anyway. You need to redesign loop, `break` is totally wrong.

Comment: As second optimization take `sizeof(v1) / (sizeof * v1)` and similar out of for() statement: it executes every cycle and it's constant.

Comment: @nopasara: The `sizeof` expressions are evaluated at compile time and folded, so that the program sees 2 and 5. Your advice would be useful for calling `strlen` in loops over strings, though.

Comment: @M Oehm: i don't really know how sizeof() will be evaluated, nether how division will be handled during compile, its up to compiler. Its just an old optimization rule: calculate constant values as early as possible and once. I'd do it just in case and there would be no place for mistake.

Comment: What is the value range of the elements?  Small numbers or the entire `[INT_MIN...INTMAX]` range?

Comment: Your array can have duplicate value too ? `{1, 2, 3, 1}`

Comment: for this kind of statement: `int v1[5] = { 1, 3, 7, 13, 10 };` it would be better to let the compiler calculate the number of elements in the array,  Therefore the statement would be better written as: `int v1[] = { 1, 3, 7, 13, 10 };`

Comment: the variables `i` and `j` can never be less than 0 so using a type of `int` results in unneeded code generation.  Suggest using a type of `size_t` for those two variables

Comment: the code block beginning with: `if (v1[i] != v2[j])` is not correct.  All that is known at that time is that the current comparison is not a match.  Suggest 1) before the inner `for()` loop, set a flag to indicate `no match found`  2) for each checked pair of values, if they are equal then change the flag state to indicate: `match found` 3) after completing the inner `for()` loop, if the flag still indicates: `no match found`, then print the value from `v1[i]`.

Comment: by the way, the `else { break; )` code block needs to be completely removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by taking any array and iterating it element by element and finding if that element is in second array too by a nested for loop and putting an if condition in the inner for loop and storing the common element in another array and then comparing both of the array one by one with that array and putting uncommon element in another array.

Like:

```
int a[min(l1,l2)], b[l], x = 0, k = 0, flag = 1;
for(int i=0; i<l1; i++){
for(int j=0; j<l2; j++){
    if(v1[i]==v2[j]){
        a[k] = v1[i];
        k++;
    }
}
}
for(int i=0; i<l1; i++){
flag = 1;
for(int j=0; j<k; j++){
    if(v1[i] == a[j]){
      flag = 0;
      break;
    }
}
if(flag==1){
    b[x] = v1[i];
    x++;
}
}

for(int i=0; i<l2; i++){
flag = 1;
for(int j=0; j<k; j++){
    if(v2[i] == a[j]){
      flag = 0;
      break;
    }
}
if(flag==1){
    b[x] = v2[i];
    x++;
}
}
```

Afterwards you can print the array.

Comment: That will work fine. I also added the break statement. Thx!

Comment: This will work only for the example arrays, where `v1 ⊃ v2`. If you change your arrays so that there are elements in `v2` that are not in `v1`, you will see that your code misses them. In other words, your code calculates the asymmetric difference `v1 - v2`, but I think the OP is looking for the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

Comment: @MOehm  check it out now? Please mention if you find any other mistakes :)

Comment: _You_ should check your code before posting. Or be confident enough to post untested code.

Comment: (But no, it doesn't work. Instead of calculating the difference `v1 - v2` directly, you now calculate it by determining the intersection `i = v1 ∩ v2` first and then calculating `v1 - i`, with the same result.)

Comment: I said use a similar loop for v2 too see the answer

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you here, because obviously that doesn't lead anywhere. But as is your accepted and twice upvoted answer is both wrong and poorly presented.

Comment: Please explain how is it wrong. I am doing v1 U v2 - i rather than v1-i. Please read the last line of my answer. I didn't write code for v2 because it was basically same as v1 and i was feeling lazy, but I don't think the answer is wrong now. If you think please enlighten me.

Comment: But you already fill `b`, so the last line is moot. And `b` has `x` elements, right? You are missing the elements in `v2` that are not in `v1`. You can enlighten yourself by testing your code. I'm not a chatter, by the way.

Comment: `int a[l], b[l]` --> `int a[min(l1,l2)], b[min(l1,l2)]`?  Else unclear the value of `l`.

Comment: Suggest formatting code to improve its presentation.

Comment: Adding that. Actually I thought of keeping it in a safe range which can be adjusted according to the question that's why I kept it an unknown variable.

Comment: On review, I am not certain about array size needs for `a[], b[]`.

Comment: No for a that is in safe range as common elements in v1 and v2 can never be greater than the number of elements of less element containing array. But for b it can be greater than min(l1,l2) so l can be taken according to the problem at hand

Answer (score 2):

An approach that is greedy in term of memory, but quick in terms of CPU cycles (linear time) is a histogram, as list comparisons in the trivial sense typically use quadratic execution complexity `:(`.

## Code Listing

---

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

    /* Allocate. */
    int numElements1 = 0;
    int numElements2 = 0;

    const int maxHistVal = UINT8_MAX + 1;
    const int maxElements = 10;
    const int minElements = 1;
    uint8_t *arr1 = NULL, *arr2 = NULL;
    uint8_t *histogram = NULL;

    /* Init random seed. */
    srand(time(NULL));

    /* Determine number of elements for each array. */
    numElements1 = (rand() % (maxElements - minElements)) + minElements;
    numElements2 = (rand() % (maxElements - minElements)) + minElements;

    /* Generate two random arrays with non-duplicated values. */
    if (NULL == (arr1 = calloc(numElements1, sizeof(uint8_t)))) {
        return ENOMEM;
    } else if (NULL == (arr2 = calloc(numElements2, sizeof(uint8_t)))) {
        free(arr1);
        return ENOMEM;
    } else if (NULL == (histogram = calloc(maxHistVal, sizeof(uint8_t)))) {
        free(arr2);
        free(arr1);
        return ENOMEM;
    } else {
        /* Have our sample arrays and histogram. Populate them and print them
         * out.
         */
        printf("ARR1: ");
        uint8_t j = 0;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < numElements1; i++) {
            /* Populate array. */
            j += (rand() % 2) + 1;
            arr1[i] = j;
            printf("%-3d ", arr1[i]);
            /* Update histogram. */
            histogram[arr1[i]]++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("ARR2: ");
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < numElements2; i++) {
            /* Populate array. */
            j += (rand() % 2) + 1;
            arr2[i] = j;
            printf("%-3d ", arr2[i]);
            /* Update histogram. */
            histogram[arr2[i]]++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        /* Print out only values that appear exactly once in the histogram. */
        printf("HISTOGRAM: UNIQUE VALUES: ");
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < maxHistVal; i++) {
            /* Print histogram. */
            if (1 == histogram[i]) {
                printf("%-3d ", i);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        /* For fun, identify the duplicates. */
        printf("HISTOGRAM: DUPLICATE VALUES: ");
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < maxHistVal; i++) {
            /* Print histogram. */
            if (1 < histogram[i]) {
                printf("%-3d ", i);
            }
        }
    }

    /* Cleanup..*/
    free(histogram);
    free(arr2);
    free(arr1);

    return 0;
}
```

## Sample Run

---

```
ARR1: 2   3   4   6   8   9   10  
ARR2: 1   2   3   4   
HISTOGRAM: UNIQUE VALUES: 1   6   8   9   10  
HISTOGRAM: DUPLICATE VALUES: 2   3   4
```

Comment: That's a nice approach for arrays with a small range of possible values thzat gives you intersection, difference and union (not shown) in one go.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks! I did a lot of math in my undergrad and masters, and love doing statistics-based models when appropriate. A hash table or sparse matrix could accommodate wider data types, but it's not quite as fast at that point.

Comment: You could write two function, less code, less bug. Your comment "/* Allocate. */" is wrong you declare/define variable here. Plus, you should only declare variable when you use it, `int numElements1 = (rand() % (maxElements - minElements)) + minElements;`. In for loop, `, j = 0` is useless. You should not `return ENOMEM;` because some value are reserved, use 0 or 1 in main.

Comment: @Stargateur `DEAD WRONG #1` If my code is deliberately being written to be C89 compliant, your statement on when I should allocate is wrong, unless I create a new block scope, which LINT will scream about. `DEAD WRONG #2:` The `j=0` in the second `for` loop indeed is necessary. `WRONG #3:` The return value is implementation dependent. `1` and `0` are only required for `exit(2)`, ie: `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. `PEDANTIC #4:` Yes, I'm declaring/defining/both at the top. The comment is to point out the initial lines of code is setting aside variables for later use.

Comment: @DevNull I think you need to write C to be "K&R C" complaint, it's the best version. By the way I upvote your answer. But your style is old. And, why do you think that exit advice only two macro?

Comment: @Stargateur My assumption of only 2 valid/portable macros is from `man 3 exit`.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Should the range of values in `a[], b[]` be limited to 0 to 63, code could use an `unsigned long long` mask.

This iterates once through each array `l1 + l2` operations, rather than a double `for()` loop with `l1 * l2` operations.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  const int v1[5] = { 1, 3, 7, 13, 10 };
  const int v2[2] = { 1, 10 };

  unsigned long long mask = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(v2) / (sizeof *v2); i++) {
    assert(v2[i] >= 0 && v2[i] < 64);
    mask |= 1ull << v2[i];
  }
  mask = ~mask;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(v1) / (sizeof *v1); i++) {
    assert(v1[i] >= 0 && v2[i] < 64);
    if ((1ull << v1[i]) & mask) {
      printf(" %d", v1[i]);
    }
  }
  puts("");
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 3 7 13
```

Comment: Array's element value wasn't limited in the question.

Comment: it's better to use uint64_t if you want a unsigned 64 bit.

Comment: @Stargateur  `uint64_t` is a good idea.  Since `unsigned long long` is at least 64-bits, this will work and I was avoiding introducing OP to too many new ideas at once. Note:  `uint_least64_t` is slight more portable than  `uint64_t`.  Of course could have used `uint_max_t` for maximum range `[0...CHAR_BIT*sizeof(uint_max_t))` with this method.

Comment: @chux I can't find what is the difference between uint_least64_t and uint64_t. Can you explain me?

Comment: @Stargateur `uint64_t` is a type that is at _exactly_ 64-bits.  `uint_least64_t` is a type  that is at _least_ 64-bits (no padding either).  Few machines do not have power-of-2 integer widths.  All C99/C11 compliant compilers implement  `uint_least64_t`.  _Nearly_ all compilers/platforms also implement the _optional_ `uint64_t, uint32_t, uint16_t, uint8_t` types.  You may never code for a machines that cannot support `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_OLD   4
#define MAX_NEW   2
int main()
{
   int old[] = {3, 4, 5, 6};
   int new[] = {4, 5};
   int temp[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
   int j = 0,z=0,i=0;
   for(i = 0; i < MAX_NEW; i++)
   {
      for(; j < MAX_OLD; j++)
      {
         if(old[j] <= new[i])
         {
            if(old[j]!=new[i])
               temp[z++] = old[j];
         }
         else
         {
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   while(j<MAX_OLD)
      temp[z++]=old[j++];
   printf("Temp[0] : %d  %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3],temp[4],temp[5],temp[6],temp[7]);
   return 0;
}
```