# How to find uncommon elements from three arrays?

Tags: data-structures

A,B,C are the *arrays* :

```
A = {1,2,3,4}
B = {8,1,2,3}
C = {1,2,9,3}
```

**Result** is the uncommon values from three *arrays*

**Result** = **{4,8,9}**

Asking for the logic what I can implement ?

Comment: I think you should tell which programming language you are using.  Unless, of course, you just want code written from scratch.

Comment: I just want the logic how can I approach
C or Python3 is my choice

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065651/c-print-only-not-common-elements-in-2-arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: Print only not common elements in 2 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065651/c-print-only-not-common-elements-in-2-arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be some other better answers. But here is the most simple one.

1. On line 4 I took the Intersection of 3 sets
2. On line 7 I took the Union of three sets
3. On line 10 the difference or XOR operation, of Union and intersection

I hope it helps:-

```
>>> a = {1,2,3,4}
>>> b = {8,1,2,3}
>>> c = {1,2,9,3}

>>> d = a & b & c
>>> print(d)
{1, 2, 3}

>>> e = a | b | c
>>> print(e)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9}

>>> f = d^e
>>> print(f)
{4, 8, 9}
```